# CreateFileAsync creates blocked file

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, storagefile

I'm working on a UWP app that needs to create a file outside of local storage.  I use a folder picker to let the user select the output director, then I store that selection using `LocalSettings` and add the folder to the `FutureAccessList`.

Then, I use [`StorageFile.CreateFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files) to create the file (which is successful, no errors or exceptions).

The problem is, the file is created with blocking, as you can see in the file properties dialog: [image]

Is there a specific way to create the file without this, or a way to unblock using C#?

Comment: are you sure you are using the right extension for the file format ??

Comment: Yes.  For testing, it's only a .txt file.  And, the file does open.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share some of my finding here:

1. Yep I can reproduce this when testing with a image. I think other files may have the same result
2. According to the following SO thread: [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374673/unblock-file-from-within-net-4-c-sharp) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535578/this-file-is-blocked-because-it-came-from-another-computer-ajax-permission-i), the property is wrote in [System.AppZoneIdentifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt805478) which is a extended property if you check it from an UWP app.(For property list you can refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/mt805470))
3. I test with code to get this [extended property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-getting-file-properties#prerequisites):

   ```
    IDictionary<string, object> extraProperties = await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(propertiesName);
       var propValue = extraProperties[appzoneProperty];
       if (propValue != null)
       {
           fileProperties.AppendLine("appzone property: " + propValue);
       }
   ```

   I always get null value. Per my understanding this may related to permission.
4. So finally I think if you need to modify this feature, you may have to consider using desktopbridge related technology to use [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher). In this way, you may be able to run win32 process to modify your file's property.

Comment: I saw those two threads also, but I believe the solutions don't apply to UWP.  The only way to link a UWP to a Win32 app is to "side load" the UWP, which is not the direction I want to go.

Comment: @JohnieKarr FullTrustProcesslancher is desktopbridge way, which is different from "sideload". You can see this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample)  The difference is that you need to add capbility and fill this [form](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge). For UWP specific solution, I'm afraid we may do not have that permission to modify this attribute.

Comment: thanks for the correction!  I'll give this route a shot.

Comment: You want [System.ZoneIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/props-system-zoneidentifier) not AppZoneIdentifier.  0 is unblocked, 3 is the mark of the web, see [URLZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.urlzone?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)