# Microsoft Defender Smart Screen Preventing my MSI to run

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer, windows-defender

I am working on a windows application. After creating the installer file i.e. MSI, it gets installed and works perfectly however, once i upload it on cloud server and try downloading it from there and install it, i get the warning message saying "Microsoft Defender Smart Screen Prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk" (below screen).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

[image]

Comment: Get a certificate and Sign it

Comment: Click on the `More info` , a button on the bottom will appear to continue. If you want to avoid this you need to sign your application with a trusted certificate.

Comment: Please see this answer: [Digital Signing & SmartScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018/50414337#50414337).

Answer (score 3):

I have linked to an answer above. Might summarize quickly:

1. ***Digital Signature***: You need an EV-Certificate to sign your setup to gain "trust outright" (Interesting concept?).
2. ***False Positive Check***: Run your binary through false-positive detection by checking with multiple anti-virus software. This site is a great help: https://www.virustotal.com. Another one you can try is: https://opentip.kaspersky.com/ (Threat Intelligence Portal). For further resources, search for "malware" here: https://www.installdude.com/jumpgate.php
3. ***Flagged Downloaded File***: You might also want to make sure the file is not flagged as downloaded from another computer:

   - [**Description of this file tagging feature here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48835413/129130) (point 2)
   - ["This file is blocked because it came from another computer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535578/this-file-is-blocked-because-it-came-from-another-computer-ajax-permission-i)

[image: Unblock]

Please check the linked answer for more details (don't want to create too many similar answers - "dual source problem" - hard to keep updated): **[How to add publisher in Installshield 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018/50414337#50414337)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can just submit your software to Microsoft for malware analysis
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission

Basically they scan the file, and establish reputation. It works even with Self-Signed Code certificates.

Comment: Have you see this actually work? As in have you submittet a file and seen it go from blocked to be reported OK?

Comment: [I found your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66462106/129130). Is there a cost for this for your own products?